# Calculate coordinates from quadrants

Tags: java, math

I know this is really simple math, but math has never been my strong suite so I'd appreciate some help.

I have 4 quadrants of 128x128 pixels. The layout is as follows:

```
-- +-
-+ ++
```

The middle of the quadrants is 0,0. So the top left is -128,-128, the bottom right is 128,128.

I need to convert a coordinate on these 4 quadrants to a coordinate in 1 of the quadrants, or a 128x128 grid. So for example, if I had (-128,-128) on the quadrants (top left), it would translate to (0,0). (128,128) would stay the same, (0,0) would translate to (64,64), etc.

I've tried various methods like testing what quadrant they're in and then doing some multiplication, which was promising, but I can't seem to perfect it.

This isn't really a language specific question, but if it matters, I'm using Java.

Here's a minimal (and bad) example of what I've already tried. I know this is in javascript, I was testing it in my browser console for simplicity.

```
function transformX(x, y) {
    var i = 0;
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) { // Bottom Right
        i = 128*2;
    } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) { // Bottom Left
        i = 128*1;
    } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) { // Top Left
        i = 128*1;
    } else if (x > 0 && y < 0) { // Top Right
        i = 128*2;
    }
    return (i+x) / 512 * 128;
}
```

This works for some things, but quickly fails. For example transformX(-128, -128) returns 0 as expected, but transformX(-1, -1) returns 31.75, when it should be 63.

Comment: Show us your attempt (include it in the question itself)

Comment: Sorry @Goion, edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to transform the range from -128...128 to 0..128 for both coordinates:

```
newx = (oldx + 128) / 2
```

Similar for `y`.

Comment: Well of course it was something this simple, should've seen that one coming. Thanks for the help!